# Prewhitening before cross-correlation

Tags: time-series, arima, cross-correlation, white-noise

i have a question concerning cross correlation and prewhitening of two time series.
I understand the common procedure to avoid spurious correlation is to model your input series x and filter the output series y by using the model of x. However, this requires prior knowledge or hypotheses on the cause-effect-relationship between the variables. If I have two variables, which might influence each other, e.g. feedback-like, how would I perform the prewhitening step? I have two approaches in mind:

1. Model both time series and then cross-correlate using residuals of x and y
2. First, treat x as predictor: model x and cross-correlate residuals of x with stationary y. Then, treat y as predictor: model y and cross-correlate residuals of y with stationary x. Each time only interpreting positive lags in the CCF.

Do you think one of these approaches is valid and/or better? Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance.